# Dynamic identifiers for struct properties

Tags: go

A user has a number of id fields - one for each type of social login:

```
type User struct {
    Name         string
    Github_id    string
    Facebook_id  string
    Google_id    string
}
```

I have variables that store the `provider` and `id`:

```
provider := "github" //could be facebook or google too
id := "12345"
```

and a user:

```
var user User
user.Name = "Bob"
```

but how can I assign the id to the correct property? I've tried:

```
if provider == "github" {
    field := "Github_id"
    user.field = id //and also user[field] = id
}
```

but no success so far.

**Additional Note**

My users may have multiple social login accounts so I can't just use a single `social_id` property as a solution to this problem.

Comment: I would recommend not doing this; use a [map](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types) instead.

Comment: Ok - could you give me an idea of what you've thinking in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performing reflection on the struct in order to fill-in the correct field seems like overkill, in this case.

I would recommend having a map field in your `User` struct to hold all of the social IDs. Example:

```
type User struct {
    Name string
    IDs  map[string]string
}

func NewUser() *User {
   return &User{
       IDs: make(map[string]string),
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
provider := "github" // could be facebook or google too
id := "12345"

user := NewUser()
user.Name = "Bob"
user.IDs[provider] = id
```

Comment: A nice, clean solution - much appreciated!